# Relationship between $\beta, \theta$ when $\sin\beta = \sin\theta, \beta \neq \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

As in the title, if we have $\sin\theta = \sin\beta$ and $\beta \neq \theta$ isn't it true that $\beta = \theta + \frac{\pi}{2}.$ If $\beta = \theta + \pi$ we should have $\sin\beta = -\sin\theta$, no?

I can't see how to show this formally is my issue here.

Comment: In the first case it is true only for $\beta=\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: the second is as you told!

Comment: Only for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ right? Because I think only $\beta = \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}; \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}$ is the only case where this is true

Comment: $\beta=\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$ and $\theta=\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$ as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the graph and see where a horizontal line intersects it. That is the answer.

Thus you have either $\theta = \beta + (\text{a multiple of } 2\pi)$ or $\beta = \pi -\theta + (\text{a multiple of } 2\pi).$

So, for example, $\sin88^\circ = \sin 92^\circ,$ since those are $(90^\circ\pm2^\circ) = (90^\circ \pm \text{something}).,$ i.e. either of them is $180^\circ$ minus the other.

Comment: The reason I am asking these random questions is I need the relationship between $\beta, \theta$ to be within $\frac{\pi}{2}$ within each other and I am not sure how to relate equality in $\sin$ to that

Comment: @danny : $\sin\left( \frac \pi 2 \pm \varepsilon\right)$ yields two equal numbers. By making $\varepsilon$ small you can make $\beta= \frac \pi 2 - \varepsilon$ and $\theta = \frac \pi 2 + \varepsilon$ as close to each other as you want. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$\sin\theta=\sin\beta\iff\begin{cases}\theta\equiv \beta\mod2\pi\\
\quad\text{or}\\\theta\equiv\pi-\beta\mod 2\pi\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 1):

From the sum formula : $\quad\sin(\beta)-\sin(\theta)=2\sin(\frac{\beta-\theta}2)\cos(\frac{\beta+\theta}2)$

We have equality when either the sinus or the cosinus annulates.

$\begin{cases}
\frac{\beta-\theta}2=k\pi\iff \beta=\theta+2k\pi\\\\
\frac{\beta+\theta}2=\frac{\pi}2+k\pi\iff \beta=(\pi-\theta)+2k\pi\\
\end{cases}$

But you can also visualize this easily graphically.

[image]

*Regarding your other question in Michael Hardy's comment section*

If you want $|\theta-\beta|\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ this means you get $(\pi-\beta)-\beta\le \frac{\pi}2\iff \beta\ge\frac{\pi}4$

Substituted in the sinus, this gives : $\theta>\beta \mid \sin(\theta)=\sin(\beta)\ge\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$.